# Facebook Sharer or Dialog - Share an Image

Tags: facebook

I did a lot of research about this, and i can't find a proper answer for my question. FB API changed this year, and most of the answers about this topic are outdated.

My problem is: I want to share a photo on facebook, but by foto i mean, the file itself, not an URL to a photo, because the look is different, and the engagement with the post is also different.

Basically, i'm asking if there's a way to do something like "sharing" an image to facebook from iPhone Gallery, but on Web:

[image: falcon]

The expected behaviour is exactly the same as the image: When user click on share, open a dialog on user's facebook with the photo pre-loaded to be shared. It's not an automatic share.

Anyone knows if this is even possible, and if possible, whats the way to do it ? I'm not expecting a full code answer, just a point to the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User Profiles: You can only share an URL that includes an image, but not an image itself. At least not anymore.

Pages: You can use the `/page-id/photos` endpoint to post photos to a Page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/

There is no way to do this with a dialog.